# Can you check if a variable is equal to any values in a dictionary

Tags: python

Hey so I've got this dict: (vl)

```
{0: 'B', 
1: 'a', 
2: 'n', 
3: 'a', 
4: 'n', 
5: 'a'}
```

Essentially it counts the position of the letter and the letter itself.

I'm trying to make something like:

```
if answer in vl:
    print("yup"+answer"Is in the word")
```

lets say `answer = 'a'`

OUTPUT:

```
yup a Is in the word" #(Banana)
```

Comment: `if answer in vl.values()`

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient way to use a dict. Dicts are all about efficient lookup by key - searching for the existence of a value requires a brute-force search. (Also, if you're just going to use integer indices starting at 0, a list does that job better.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your dictionary, you can `dict.values()`:

```
vl = {0: 'B', 
      1: 'a', 
      2: 'n', 
      3: 'a', 
      4: 'n', 
      5: 'a'}

answer = input("Input the answer: ")

if answer in vl.values():
    print(f"yup, {answer} is in the word.")
```

But if the dictionary is there mainly for the indexes, you should instead use `enumerate(iterable))`

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question, what does the f in print(f"string") signify?

Comment: It is called a formatted string. It basically lets us conveniently insert variables into the strings.